# Correct My DB2 Query that I am Getting Error

Tags: db2

I am using below DB2 query to get the Specific Length of Character
from CLASSIFICATION Coulmn with Condition 0 before the '\', but I am getting error.

```
select SERVICE_REQUEST,

(case when 
    (SUBSTR(CLASSIFICATION,LOCATE('\',CLASSIFICATION)-2,1))='0' then
        RIGHT(CLASSIFICATION,LENGTH(CLASSIFICATION)-LOCATE('\',CLASSIFICATION))
    ELSE CLASSIFICATION
end) 
as CLASSIFICATION2

 from REPORTDB3.MAXIMO_INDIA_SR_MONTHLY_REPORT where length(SERVICE_REQUEST)=7
```

ERROR:

```
An error occurred while processing the results. - 
The statement was not executed because a numeric argument of a scalar function is out of range.. SQLCODE=-138, SQLSTATE=22011, DRIVER=4.19.56
```

Can you please Help me on this.

Regards,
Sambit

Already Gone to Stackoverflow for the answers

Comment: Please, provide your Db2 version, a number of different values in the `CLASSIFICATION` column and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should care about the situations, when the `CLASSIFICATION` column data have the following problems:
- No `\` characters at all
- `\` character in the 1-st 2 positions
Your query passes negative 2-nd parameter to the `SUBSTR` function in these cases, which is not allowed.

```
with REPORTDB3_MAXIMO_INDIA_SR_MONTHLY_REPORT(CLASSIFICATION, SERVICE_REQUEST) as (
values 
  ('ab0c|def', '1234567')
, ('\def', '1234567')
, ('a\def', '1234567')
, ('ab0c\def', '1234567')
)
select SERVICE_REQUEST, CLASSIFICATION,
case SUBSTR(CLASSIFICATION, case when pos>2 then pos end -2, 1)
  when '0' then SUBSTR(CLASSIFICATION, pos+1)
  else CLASSIFICATION
end as CLASSIFICATION2
from (
select SERVICE_REQUEST, CLASSIFICATION, LOCATE('\', CLASSIFICATION) as pos
from REPORTDB3_MAXIMO_INDIA_SR_MONTHLY_REPORT
where length(SERVICE_REQUEST)=7
)
```